# FOlder Watcher - Cocoa/Obj C

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I need to watch a specified folder for specific type of file (pdf) and get notification only when file is "Created" or "Renamed".
I tried many Obj c wrappers like SCEvents, UKKQueue etc., I could not get the type of the event raised("Created" or "Renamed") inside the notification delegate.I am just getting a flag/some#.I also tried FSEventStream which was not raising callback.Refered URL for this:[OSX FSEventStreamEventFlags not working correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18415285/osx-fseventstreameventflags-not-working-correctly).

In SCEvents, I have below delegate which is not telling me the type of event-

```
- (void)pathWatcher:(SCEvents *)pathWatcher eventOccurred:(SCEvent *)event {

    NSLog(@"%@", event);
}
```

Getting below log-

```
2014-02-27 16:41:59.342 PMLauncher6[5187:303] <SCEvent { eventId = 661674, eventPath = /Users/Test, eventFlag = 67584 } >
```

Any one has any idea on the same or better way to meet the requirement, kindly advise.

Thanks

---

Answer (score 2):

Try `NSWorkspace` - `noteFileSystemChanged:`.

The documentation doesn't tell much about it, but as a Notification that "Informs the NSWorkspace object that the file system changed at the specified path." it should fit to your needs.

Comment: Looked at NSWorkSpace documentation. Looks like all of these methods seems to be depricated...                                  Deprecated in OS X v10.6. Use the FSEvents API described in FSEvents Reference instead.) https://developer.apple.com/librarY/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/FSEvents_Ref/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004723     Any other advise?

Comment: You're right, some are, but "noteFileSystemChanged:" is still alive. Watch the ":" please. Haven't worked with FSEvents.

Comment: Thanks. Do you have any usage example for the same? How to get the callback/delegate when folder is changed.