# Does FSEvents and FSEventStreamRef guarantee order of events?

Tags: macos, cocoa, xcode5, osx-mavericks, osx-yosemite

I am using FSEventStreamRef to register for file events on a particular directory. Does FSEventStreamRef guarantee that the order of events correspond to the order in which the changes are made to the File system?

For example

1) I create a new folder with name 'untitled folder'
2) I rename this newly created folder to 'MyFolder'

Can I safely assume that I would get 2 events (in the below order)

First corresponding to the new folder create having the file name as 'untitled folder'
Second event with kFSEventStreamEventFlagItemRenamed flag set and having file Path as 'MyFolder'

Comment: Maybe this answer is helpful? http://stackoverflow.com/a/20854586/210171 I posted some code there for using FSEvents.

Comment: I am able to use the FS Events API. It seems to be working fine. I am relying on order of events to detect if a file was renamed but could find no information if the API guarantees that the order of events is the same as the order in which actions take place on the file system.

Comment: The events are ORd together I believe--so you can't tell what happened first just from FSEvents. (See my linked answer)

Comment: I understand that when events are Ord together it is not possible to tell the order. But is it guaranteed that if there are two separate events they are delivered in the same order as the changes were made on the file system. In other words is the order preserved across events?

Comment: I don't know anything more, sorry.